# tcpdump only showing beacon packets for certain mac address filters

Tags: wireless-networking, router, tcpdump

I'm using an ubuntu OS to capture data packets in monitor mode (https://sandilands.info/sgordon/capturing-wifi-in-monitor-mode-with-iw)

The command I'm using to capture packets from my laptop is:
sudo tcpdump -i mon0 -w test.pcap wlan host xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

(where xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is my laptop wireless card mac address)

This works fine and I'm collecting all packets, including data packets, if I stream something on youtube.

However, if I do the exact same thing with my router's wireless card mac address, I only capture beacon packets...

I've set the channel frequency to be the same and the network has no encryption for both.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Many APs (i.e. "wireless routers") have two or more [W]LAN-side MAC addresses. One for the 802.11 radio, one for the Ethernet interface that connects to the internal 4-port LAN Ethernet switch, and maybe a third for the software bridge device that bridges packets between LAN and WLAN.

However, since they usually only have one [W]LAN-side IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.1) they have to pick one of those MAC addresses to be the one associated with their LAN-side IP address.

So look in your client's ARP table to see what MAC address is associated with the router's LAN IP address and filter on that.